# On my shared Linux webserver apache user is same as my user, is that standard?

Tags: linux

I ran the following command, when logged into my shared Linux host to see what user Apache was running as:

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

And it was the same user that I use on the server.

ie.

```
myuser@example.com [~/public_html]# ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
myuser  44904  0.0  0.0  61244   724 pts/0    S+   15:43   0:00 egrep (apache|httpd)
```

Is that standard for shared hosts? On my development computer apache runs under the user `www-data`, and in documentation or tutorials on file permissions for certain CMS environments, I see reference to Apache working under the user `www-data` all the time.

Comment: I usually see this on nonshared servers. May be they can easily identify the user and its webuser.

Answer (score 1):

Webservers run with www-data as user, as what you saw is just the process of the command you typed

Comment: How would one check to confirm this? I was using this http://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as

Comment: You can use this `cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep APACHE_RUN_USER` or grep the user instead `ps aux | grep www-data`

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know off the top of your head the command to use for CentOS?

Comment: `ps aux | grep httpd`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it returns the same value as my user I'm logged in as. I think for the shared host it apparently sets apache to use the same user as the owner of the account.

Comment: Shared host webservers uses user `nobody`

Comment: On a shared host, Apache cannot run as the user nor is this a good idea for security. Apache always installs to use a made-up non-privileged user name typically *www-data*. I have seen *nobody* on older installs though it can/may still be used in some cases. It all depends upon the install since the packages will vary depending upon the OS and who created the package.